# Can a power surge pass through a household DC power adapter?

Tags: power-supply, surge-protection

I assume that all DC adapters for household electronics use a bridge rectifier.  Is that (still) correct, or are other designs now in common use for household AC-DC converters?

Without explicitly adding surge protection components and circuitry (MOVs, etc.), do any of these common AC-DC converter designs do anything to attenuate voltage spikes, or otherwise isolate the DC output from spikes on the AC side?  If so, how?

Comment: Are you asking if there are AC/DC adaptors with built in surge protection?

Comment: No, I'm asking whether the _standard_ designs of AC/DC adapters offer any surge isolation, and if so, how.

Answer (score 1):

In a typical flyback or LLC adapter there is some attenuation to surges just by virtue of the input bulk cap, the switching regulation loop, the output filter and the MOV on the input filter (and/or any TVS devices the designer added.)

However, there's always the potential of a large enough surge to do damage. (E.g. a nearby direct lightning strike.)

Comment: What exactly does the abbreviation LLC mean? Google comes up with tons of material about LLC resonance converters and SMPS but there is no mentioning about what LLC actually stands for.

Comment: LLC isn't an abbreviation in the traditional sense.  Traditionally an inductor is given a reference designation starting with "L", and a capacitor "C".  So the LLC refers to the resonant inductor "L", the transformer magnetizing inductance "L" and the resonant capacitor "C".

Comment: Oh, thats nearly  a case of "I haven't seen the wood for the trees". Thanks for clarifying.